# How to change a column value based on date (every year)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a leave management system, and this is my first web application. I have a LocalDB sql server in visual studio 2010 and I need some columns to be updated every year.

For example, I have SickLeave column (int), I need this column to be updated with the value (15) in a specific date (every year), the date will be different from one employee to another based on his joining date.

I have searched a lot, there is something called scheduled event in mySQL that can do something similar, but it doesn't work for sql server.

So anyone has an idea how to do it? Your help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider (re)designing your system in such a way that such periodic jobs are not needed. There is always a chance that the scheduled job will not run, or run several times, or run at inappropriate time.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov Thanks for your advice. I will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SQL Agent Job.

SQL Agent: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx

Create a Job: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268.aspx

We use these for all sorts of scheduled tasks.

In your case you could create Job that runs Daily, the job can execute a StoredProc (or simple Update statement).

`UPDATE Employee SET SickLeave = 15 WHERE DAY(JoinedDate) = DAY(GETDATE()) AND MONTH(JoinedDate) = MONTH(GETDATE())`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.
I will try it.